# bootstrap4 content/div align

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Please look at a codepen for this:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/anderson234/pen/ZNEjEB?editors=1100)

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container position-relative">
   <div class="pillwrapper">
      <div class="rightpart d-flex justify-content-end">
         <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mypill">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#content-1" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">button</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#content-2" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">button</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#content-3" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">button</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content" id="mypillcontent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="content-1">
               <p>content here</p>
               <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162140/duckling-birds-yellow-fluffy-162140.jpeg" alt="" class="content-photo position-absolute" />
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content-2">
              <p>content here</p>
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162140/duckling-birds-yellow-fluffy-162140.jpeg" alt="" class="content-photo position-absolute" />
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content-3">
              <p>content here</p>
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162140/duckling-birds-yellow-fluffy-162140.jpeg" alt="" class="content-photo position-absolute" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm learning bootstrap4. I'm trying to realize a structure here with bootstrap NAV PILL: a tab system(but looks like buttons), you can switch tabs, under a tab there is a text content and a photo, only this photo will be shown in the left, looks like tabs system is right part, photo is left part. Problem is: 1, the first tab is active, when I click any other one, nothing happens. 2, why position-absolute does not work, photo still at right? 3, how to put text content under tabs, and horizontally align center the tab and content?

```
.rightpart{
  border:2px solid red;
  min-height:100vh;
}
.pillwrapper{
  border:1px solid green;
  min-height:100vh;
}
.container{
  border:1px solid yellow;
  min-height:100vh;
}
.content-photo{
  width:200px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bootstrap 4, the 'tabs' are not actually tabbable until you include the JavaScript plugin to make the tabs work. The documentation for Bootstrap states this:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs

To see the tabs work, see this link from the Bootstrap documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

The above links show the tabs working with content associated with each tab. To have content 'under' each tab, you need to have **tab-pane**s for the content for each tab. See this example from the Bootstrap documentation.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

To center the tab navigation and content under each tab, you could use CSS like below for the tab navigation (from the above example HTML).

```css
.nav {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

With this information, your HTML should look more like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">

        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#content-1" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Button 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#content-2" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Button 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#content-3" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Button 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="mypillcontent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content-1">
                <p>Content Here</p>
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162140/duckling-birds-yellow-fluffy-162140.jpeg" alt="" class="content-photo position-absolute" />
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content-2">
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="content-3">
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>


<!--
Add Bootstrap JavaScript
-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Comparing your code with mine, I find 'bootstrap.min.js' is the key for tab switching. Isn't ".min.js" included in ".js"? LOL, never knew this. Anyway, now I have this code /w only one problem left: [link](https://codepen.io/anderson234/pen/NVWeGg) Please take a look, why pic still not going to left part?